# Special triangles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles

I have this question that I have the answer to but no working how to get it, is it by pure memorization of angles or there some steps?

> Without a calculator, determine, in radians, the angles of a right-angled triangle with sides $3$, $6$, and $3\sqrt{3}$.

The answer $\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$,and $\frac{\pi}{3}$ but how do I get that is there some formula?

Comment: Have you learned about sine, cosine, and tangent?

Comment: Yes I have learnt a lot of stuff moe complex than this I figure I am just not grasping the conncept.

Comment: @MarkWallberg I would first suggest drawing a picture. It'll make using sin, cos, and tan much easier

Comment: Thanks I should have mentioned without a calculator in the question

Comment: Do you know about degrees vs radians?

Comment: I understand all of the concepts I just am not sur ehow to apply them to solve a question like this.

Comment: When one side is double another side check for the ratio,  x, x* root(3), 2x,  also written 1, root(3), 2  Three sides of a triangle in this ratio are always a right triangle.  Together with 45-45-90 triangle, the two special right triangles, come up frequently enough students desiring A's will find memorizing the ratio & angles very useful.  Thankfully, memorizing a diagram is easier than merely angles or ratios.

Comment: Yeah, without a calculator it comes down to knowing that since the sides are of the form $\{a, 2a, a\sqrt{3}\}$, it must what most teachers call a "30-60-90" triangle, or in this case a "$\frac{\pi}{6}$-$\frac{\pi}{3}$-$\frac{\pi}{2}$" triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a right triangle, any angle say $\alpha$ can be determined using Sine as follows $$\sin\alpha=\frac{\text{side opposite to the angle}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$$
Hence, the angle opposite to the side of length $3$
$$ \sin\alpha=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}=\sin \frac{\pi}{6}$$ $$\implies \color{blue}{\alpha=\frac{\pi}{6}}$$ 
Similarly, the angle say $\beta$ opposite to the side of length $3\sqrt{3}$
$$\sin\beta=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{6}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\sin \frac{\pi}{3}$$ $$\implies \color{blue}{\beta=\frac{\pi}{3}}$$It is clear that angles of right triangle are $\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{\pi}{3}$ & $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely prove it using trigonometry:it wouldn't be particularly hard. ($\pi/2$ has to be one of the angles since its a right triangle, $\alpha=\sin^{-1} (3/6)=\pi/6$, $\beta = \sin^{-1} (3\sqrt{3}/6) = \pi/3$). However, if you remember back to geometry, since this triangle has sides in the ratio $1:\sqrt{3}:2$, you know the angles are 30, 60, and 90 degrees. Converting to radians is trivial from there.

So there is a formula, but the 30-60-90 right triangle is such a common and useful relationship that it's one I'd memorize.